# How to keep empty directories in Azure blob storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I use **BlobContainerClient** from `Azure.Storage.Blobs` library. I try to delete some files in **Blob Container**. When I do so, and if some directories get empty after deletions, these directories also disappear and can no longer be seen in Azure Portal.

I need to keep all empty directories in Container. How is it possible?

*Also, this question could be formulated this way:

how is it possible to create an empty directory in Azure Storage?*

Comment: Keep a small dummy file in each directory you don't want deleted.

Comment: @rossum That makes sense, but I need to empty some directories. The idea is to create empty directories somehow.

Comment: You can use Data Lake Gen 2 account or use File Service instead of Blob Storage. Regular blob storage does not have a concepts of folders.

Comment: @GauravMantri yes, actually I checked this resource about how to convert the existing one/create a new one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-namespace
But, wondered, how it is possible to find out from C# whether storage has enabled EnableHierarchicalNamespace or not?

Comment: Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobserviceclient.getaccountinfo?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-blobserviceclient-getaccountinfo(system-threading-cancellationtoken).

Comment: @GauravMantri can you please share any examples? I can not see GetAccountInfo in Azure.Storage.Blobs namespace.

Comment: What version of SDK you’re using? The link I shared is for the latest version.

Comment: @MishoZhghenti - I would start with the docs, as the link was already provided to you. This really isn't the place to ask someone to build a new example.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thank you for sharing the resource. Yes, I was using an old version.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to keep empty directories in Azure Blob Storage if the **Hierarchical namespace is disabled**

To keep the empty directories in Azure Blob Storage, you need to use **Data Lake Gen2 Storage Account**

To check if the Hierarchical namespace is enabled or disabled, you can use below lines of C# code:

```
var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
AccountInfo accountInfo = serviceClient.GetAccountInfo();
Console.WriteLine(accountInfo.IsHierarchicalNamespaceEnabled);
```

You need to use latest version of **Azure.Storage.Blobs** namespace. The package version is
**Azure.Storage.Blobs v12.10.0**

Comment: There's no need for an answer - the OP already figured out their issue - it was based on an outdated SDK. Just vote to close as 'typo or could not reproduce'. Also: everything needed was already presented in comments, pointing the OP in the right direction.